# How to work with LDAP aliases?

Tags: apache-directory-studio

Using the latest version of Apache Directory Studio, which is 2.0.0.v20210717-M17:

How can I differentiate between a regular LDAP entry and an alias to such an entry? They look all the same to me. I think there is some option to show if something is an alias or not, but I can't find it. The [user's guide](https://nightlies.apache.org/directory/studio/2.0.0.v20200411-M15/userguide/Apache_Directory_Studio_LDAP_Browser_User_Guide.pdf) says:

> Disable the options "Finding Base DN" and "Search" in the "Aliases
> Dereferencing" group of the Connection properties. This setting will
> display alias entries in the tree.

But I don't see such options. Where do I have to look?

And how can I delete an alias? I see only “Delete entry” in the context menu, which also deletes the entry the alias points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found those “Alias Dereferencing” options which I had to uncheck. They are below the tab “Browser Options”:

[image: "Browser Options" tab]

Then aliases will have a different icon in the tree. Also “Delete entry” then deletes the alias, not the entry it points to.